# How to mount source code in a Devcontainer at build time?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, conan, devcontainer

### Context:

I am creating my first devcontainer on Visual Studio Code. I want the locally cloned repo on the host machine to be both available at build time (I need the Conan-related files `conanfile.py` and profiles to be available installing dependencies in the image) and then run-time (for compiling/running/debugging code etc).

### What I tried

The `devcontainer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "C++",
    "workspaceMount": "source=${localWorkspaceFolder},target=/app,type=bind",
    "workspaceFolder": "/app", 
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile"
    },
    "features": {},
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "settings": {},
            "extensions": [
                "streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:3.17.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache \
        build-base=0.5-r3 \
        cmake=3.24.4-r0 \ 
        python3=3.10.13-r0 \
        py3-pip=22.3.1-r1

RUN pip install conan==1.61.0
RUN conan install conanfile.py
```

### Problem

The files are not found during the build stage: `ERROR: Conanfile not found at /app/conanfile.py`

However, when I comment out the `conan install` part, the image is built properly and I can see the files with a `ls`.

I think I misunderstand the default mounting of devcontainers and how to mount files properly at build stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build the container image `vscode` basically just executes a `docker build` with the specified `Dockerfile`.

The `workspaceMount` and `workspaceFolder` options have no effect on the build but are only used when creating and running the dev container from the image.

So if you need some files from your source at build time you first need to `COPY` them into the image, e.g.:

```docker
# ...

COPY conanfile.py /app/
RUN conan install conanfile.py
```

If you don't want to store the copied file(s) in the image you could use [`RUN --mount=type=bind`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run---mounttypebind):

```docker
# ...

# bind mount the source to /app/
# note that source=/ refers to the root of the context folder, i.e., our workspaceFolder
RUN --mount=type=bind,source=/,target=/app/ conan install conanfile.py
```

But these both would only work correctly if the command (`conan install conanfile.py`) does not modify the contents of `/app/` (e.g. installing dependencies etc. into it) because with the first approach those changes would be overriden with the contents of your workspace folder at run-time when it is bind-mounted into the container.
And with the second approach building your image would require to modify the contents of the bind-mounted workspace folder, which has a whole lot of other pitfalls.

In such a case you probably should rather use [`onCreateCommand`, `updateContentCommand`, `postCreateCommand` or `postStartCommand`](https://containers.dev/implementors/json_reference/#lifecycle-scripts) to run the command at run-time only:

```json
{
    "name": "C++",
    "workspaceMount": "source=${localWorkspaceFolder},target=/app,type=bind",
    "workspaceFolder": "/app", 
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile"
    },
    "onCreateCommand": "conan install conanfile.py",
    "features": {},
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "settings": {},
            "extensions": [
                "streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this thorough answer! One question related to this: where does the `COPY` look first? in the `/` (root project folder) or in the folder that contains the `devcontainer.json`? How to edit this default ?

Comment: I think I found it in the [build.context](https://containers.dev/implementors/json_reference/#image-specific) documentation: 
Path that the Docker build should be run from relative to devcontainer.json. For example, a value of ".." would allow you to reference content in sibling directories. Defaults to ".".

Comment: Indeed the onCreateCommand approach worked properly. Does it mean there is no way to store the built conan dependencies in the docker image?

Comment: I'm not familiar with conan and it depends. In general you of course can store the results of that build step in the image. But if these results are stored in the directory of the source code (`/app`) it gets complicated, because that directory will be overshadowed with your workspace folder at run time. Also you would have to rebuild the container image every time relevant parts of your code changes to re-run conan.

Comment: On the other hand if the build results are stored in your source code directory anyway you would not need to put the conan build into the image/container but just have to run conan on a fresh checkout of the code once and then the results are stored in your source code directory. Thus you don't have to re-run conan the next time you start vscode.